# PC wont post after wrong bios update

Tags: amd-ryzen

I accidentally updated to the wrong version of the bios on my Biostar TB350-BTC motherboard and now my computer doesn’t post, i can’t access the bios, but the fans and power are still working. I’ve tried using the jumper, changing ram dimm slots, reseating the processor, booting without storage, and removing and replacing the CMOS battery. Any other ideas? i’m not sure if my motherboard supports USB bios flashback, but if it didn’t that would be a surefire way to fix it. i’m currently using a Biostar TB350-BTC Am4 motherboard, ryzen 3 2200G, 1 stick of 8GB  Team elite plus ddr4, Gigabyte radeon RX550, and a 500gb samsung evo ssd with 1tb toshiba 7200 rpm mechanical.

Comment: Read this pdf, go to last method and see if it works for you>>>>>>>https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/manual/bios_update.pdf

Comment: it didn’t work, my monitor doesn’t move off of the no signal screen, so i can’t actually get into my bios.

Answer (score -1):

if it still matters to you: if by wrong BIOS you mean earlier version BIOS then be advised your system  wont post if your processor has a manufacture date after the date of the BIOS. i have same board and it came with a BIOS from 2017 and my ryzen 7 and ryzen 3 processors wouldn't work until after i reverted to a AMD A10-9700 cpu/apu and then updated BIOS to latest version, then my ryzen 3 and ryzen 7 cpu s worked, and of course, for those that may not know, the processor has to be an APU graphics version if u gots no GPU card.